# Timber - Pagination didn't work with default Wordpress query

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

I'm trying to display pagination in my default query on blog page.
So I have file called home.php with this code

```
<?php

use Timber\Post;
use Timber\Timber;

$post = new Post();

$context = Timber::context();
$context['post'] = $post;

global $paged;
if (!isset($paged) || !$paged){
    $paged = 1;
}

$args = [
    'post_staus' => 'published',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
    'offset' => 1,
];
$context['posts'] = Timber::get_posts($args);

$argsNewest = [
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'offset' => 0,
];
$context['latest'] = Timber::get_posts($argsNewest);

Timber::render('page-home.twig', $context);
```

In the page-home.twig I'm trying to display my pagination but without any success.

```
{% include 'partial/pagination.twig' with { pagination: posts.pagination({show_all: false, mid_size: 3, end_size: 2}) } %}
```

The other weird thing is when I'm trying to dump posts like `{{ dump(posts) }}` it's not working however loop like `{% for post in posts %}` working fine and I can display posts.

So my questions:

1. Why my pagination didn't work?
2. Why my dump not working but loop yes?

Answer (score 0):

1. You could use the pre_get_posts filter so you can use the default WP_Query.

In your `functions.php` file, add this code (or append to existing pre_get_posts filter)

```
function modify_blog_posts_query($query) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 2 );
        $query->set( 'paged', (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 );
        $query->set( 'offset', 1 );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modify_blog_posts_query' );
```

You might need to add `use Timber\PostQuery;` at the top of your code.

In your home.php file, replace

```
$args = [
    'post_staus' => 'published',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
    'offset' => 1,
];
$context['posts'] = Timber::get_posts($args);
```

with

```
$context['posts'] = new Timber\PostQuery();
```

See https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/pagination/ on how to use pagination in Twig.
See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/ for more information on the pre_get_posts filter.

2. For the dump function, try the Twig dump function again with this new code above.